# is it possible to write an application that can block call, disable writing text messages if you are driving

Tags: iphone, ios

is it possible to write an application that can block call, disable writing text messages if you are driving  or moving fast, regardless of any version of IOS?

Comment: turn off your iphone when you're driving :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, iPhone apps do not have access to the phone or sms text systems.

There may be such apps in the jailbreak community, but nothing like it will be in the App Store.